# SSIS Excel Data Import - Mixed data type in Rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sqldatatypes

I am trying to import excel data using SSIS pkg but it is changing data type and converting to some other format with decimal.

I pull data from a set range

Example:
Range `A5:AB20`

My data Column A5 (M)= `1.2`

SSIS Import something like `120000.001237`

I was SSIS to import A5 = `1.2`

I tried this but am failing...

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ABCDPrograms.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";`

Original Data is imported from some legacy system and I cannot make changes there.

Kindly direct. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"?   Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Derived Column transformation in your dataflow task between the Excel spreadsheet and the database:

Excel file, I know you say your spreadsheet is showing 1.2 but I can't see what's in the cell, so it does look like the larger value is what is held in the cell:

[image]

Derived transformation task, rounds the value (divided by 100000) to 1 decimal place, replacing the column value:

[image]

Resulting database entry, this column's datatype is set to DECIMAL(8,1) or however many preceeding digits you need):

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you TJB - I should've added ..
There is lot of other data before Row 5 and after row 20. These values get calculated somewhere else in the sheet (or even other worksheets). Row5-20 is 'linked' and shows 1.2 (if clicked it will show formula with linked cells or sheets)

So in reality, it is something like scrapping what ever is shown (i.e. 1.2)

Comment: OK, but nonethless it would appear that the 120k value is getting passed to the SSIS package.  Assuming you are correctly identifying the column from your spreadsheet in your SSIS package and you have set the SQL table up correctly then this should still work.  

Another possibility is that you are incorrectly mapping a cell with 120k in it to your SQL column, when you should be choosing the 1.2 column.  It would be some pretty funky custom formatting on the Excel spreadsheet to get the 120k to look like 1.2, rather than a formula.

Comment: Testing your solution, will let you know the results.. thank you TJB