# Excel Data values returned as null when load to SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have an odd thing happening with importing data from Excel to SQL Server.

*This is my sample source data*

[image: This is my sample source data]

*The value become null after import to SQL Server*

[image: The value become null after import to SQL Server]

Basically, other part of excel work well. But only for this area, the value become null. The data type is float which I haven't convert it to numeric or nvarchar.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Excel Data Seems to Randomly Give Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369804/importing-excel-data-seems-to-randomly-give-null-values)

Comment: I already tried add IMEX=1 to the connection and it not working. For cache, im not that sure, since i did remake it few times work flow but still null value and there 1 time where the it failed to read all data from excel which need to restart ssdt.

Comment: the IMEX =1 problem could not find installable isam even though it already run 32 bit

Comment: @JohnMee have you tried to add IMEX=1 and to disable reading headers from the first row, please read all details in the link above