# Failing to read String value from an excel column

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis, script-task

SSIS script task reading only numeric values of excel but fails to read the alphanumeric values present in the same column

I've tried using IMEX=0, IMEX=1 and IMEX=2. But the Alphanumeric values are being generated as NULL in my SQL server table.

```
//Excel Connection String
string ConStr;
ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + 
";IMEX=0\"";
```

If the 1st 8 column 'A' values are integer (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and then comes alphanumeric (A,B,ABQX345) values in below rows, then it should read all the values as it is and insert into SQL Server table as

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,A,B,ABQX345
```

Comment: Welcome to the (awful) world of the ACE drivers, and that they don't care what your data type really is, it'll infer it incorrectly whether you like it or not (I realise this isn't a constructive comment).

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a script task in the Control Flow to read an excel file? Normally you read an such things in a Data Flow and you would use a Excel Connection Manager and Excel Source.

Comment: The first value in the excel file has to be string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is related to the OLEDB provider used to read excel files: Since excel is not a database where each column has a specific data type, OLEDB provider tries to identify the dominant data types found in each column and replace all other data types that cannot be parsed with NULLs.

There are many articles found online discussing this issue and giving several workarounds *(links listed below)*.

But after using SSIS for years, I can say that **best practice is to convert excel files to csv files and read them using Flat File components**.

Or, if you don't have the choice to convert excel to flat files then you can force excel connection manager to ignore headers from the first row bu adding `HDR=NO` to the connection string and adding `IMEX=1` to tell the OLEDB provider to specify data types from the first row *(which is the header - all string most of the time)*, in this case all columns are imported as string and no values are replaced with NULLs but you will lose the headers and a additional row (header row is imported).

If you cannot ignore the header row, just add a dummy row that contains dummy string values *(example: `aaa`)* after the header row and add `IMEX=1` to the connection string.

#### SchemaMapper Excel Import class

In addition, it is good to check the following class which is a part of SchemaMapper project, I implemented the logic mentioned above in order to fix this problem:

- [SchemaMapper - MsExcelImport.cs](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/blob/master/SchemaMapperDLL/Classes/Converters/MsExcelImport.cs)

**Helpful links**

- [SSIS Excel Data Import - Mixed data type in Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104559/ssis-excel-data-import-mixed-data-type-in-rows)
- [Mixed data types in Excel column](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/06/mixed-data-types-in-excel-column.html)
- [Importing data from Excel having Mixed Data Types in a column (SSIS)](https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/importing-data-from-excel-having-mixed-data-types-in-a-column-ssis/)
- [Why SSIS always gets Excel data types wrong, and how to fix it!](https://www.concentra.co.uk/resources/articles/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/)
- [EXCEL IN SSIS: FIXING THE WRONG DATA TYPES](https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/excel-in-ssis-fixing-the-wrong-data-types/)
- [IMEX= 1 extended properties in ssis](http://bageshkumarbagi-msbi.blogspot.com/2016/03/imex-1-extended-properties-in-ssis.html)

Comment: I have never seen the HDR=NO to get all strings trick (+1). I just hate Excel sources because I know a person made it / touched it / did something to it (truncate leading 0's for example) and it will have other errors as well.